# Aggregate functions in query against view in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view, aggregate

I am utilizing some aggregate in a query against a column PRICE in a view called ORDERS.

Here how my ORDERS view was created

```
CREATE VIEW ORDERS as
SELECT CUSTOMER, SUM(total) PRICE
FROM RECORDS
GROUP BY CUSTOMER;
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT PRICE, AVG(PRICE), MIN(PRICE), MAX(PRICE)
FROM ORDERS;
```

My error is:
    Error report -
    SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

I'm really unfamiliar with the error and can't find a lot on the error beyond connection issues. How do I solve this?

Comment: Strange error. However, you can either show separate prices (`SELECT PRICE`) or show aggregates (`SELECT AVG(PRICE), MIN(PRICE), MAX(PRICE)`, not both at the same time.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.

Comment: If you follow the general GROUP BY rule, you'll never go wrong: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." In your case PRICE is used in both at the same time, which can't be done. Either select as column, or use as argument to a set function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems wrong as PRICE column is different and you are not grouping by it, I believe this is a typo and this is what causing your error... Exclude the price column like this:(although I haven't seen this error before, I assume its the reason)

```
SELECT AVG(PRICE), MIN(PRICE), MAX(PRICE)
FROM ORDERS;
```